# best way to fill in a numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I use the following code to generate an image with a gradient. I access the array element by element. Is there a better way to do it? Thanks.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

x = np.ndarray((256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8)
for i in xrange(256):
    for j in xrange(256):
        for k in xrange(3):
            x[i, j, k] = i
cv2.imwrite('SYxmp_out.jpg', x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you aim to fill `x[i, j, k]` with `i` for all values for *i*, *j* and *k*.

You can construct such array with:

```
x = np.repeat(np.arange(256, dtype=np.uint8), (256*3)).reshape(256, 256, 3)
```

We then obtain an array that looks like:

```
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(256, dtype=np.uint8), (256*3)).reshape(256, 256, 3)
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        ...,
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  1,   1,   1],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        ...,
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  1,   1,   1]],

       [[  2,   2,   2],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [  2,   2,   2],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        [  2,   2,   2]],

       ...,

       [[253, 253, 253],
        [253, 253, 253],
        [253, 253, 253],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [253, 253, 253],
        [253, 253, 253]],

       [[254, 254, 254],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [254, 254, 254],
        ...,
        [254, 254, 254],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [254, 254, 254]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        ...,
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

For the second axis, we could make use of `np.tile`:

```
>>> np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(256, dtype=np.uint8), 3), 256).reshape(256, 256, 3)
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       ...,

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   1,   1],
        [  2,   2,   2],
        ...,
        [253, 253, 253],
        [254, 254, 254],
        [255, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

although if things are more complex, broadcasting might be a better idea. For example for the first dimension we can use:

```
x = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))
x[:] = np.arange(256)[:,None,None]
```

whereas for the second one, we can make use of:

```
x = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))
x[:] = np.arange(256)[None,:,None]
```

or without mentioning 256 twice:

whereas for the second one, we can make use of:

```
x = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))
x[:] = np.arange(x.shape[0])[:,None,None]

# second dimension
x = np.zeros((256, 256, 3))
x[:] = np.arange(x.shape[1])[None,:,None]
```

**Benchmarks:**

If I run the code in the question (`f`), and the code in the answer (`g`), and the broadcasthing version (`h`) hundred times on an *i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz*, the I obtain the following benchmarks:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=100)
3.1465475099976175
>>> timeit(g, number=100)
0.05008594098035246
>>> timeit(h, number=100)
0.03603723298874684
```

So this should mean a speedup of approximately 62 times for `g` over `f`, and a speedup of approximately 87 for `h` over `f`.

Comment: In terms of the code, it is not that simple. But at least it should be faster than my original code?

Comment: @user1424739: we first generate a range with `.arange()`, so `[0,1,2,3,...,255]`. Next we repeat it `3*256` times, so it now is `[0,0,0,..., 0, 1, 1, ..., 1, ..., 255, ...., 255]`, and then we reshape it to the requested size. Normally it should be faster. Although the amount of data is not that large.

Comment: Also, to assign `j` instead of `i`, how your code will be changed? Sounds like the for-loop is rather intuitive, but the matrix syntax is less so. One dimension of two 256's has to be repeated, this is also annoying.

Comment: @user1424739: running benchmarks gives a speedup of approximately 62. That's not very impressive, but as said, there is not that much data, so numpy can not take full benefit of processing in "bulk".

Comment: @user1424739: as for `for` loops, coming from a functional programming world where there are no loops, it looks quite "ugly" since it makes something inherently sequential. :)

Comment: I understand that. But one of the two 256's has to be specified twice in your array version code. That means, when I change the dimension, I have to change the code at two places. This is not convenient.

Comment: @user1424739: not per se, you can make use of broadcasting, see edit.